# Exponential of Lie bracket

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $g$ the associated Lie algebra. Let $X,Y\in g$. Is there a formula in term of $a=\exp(tX)$ and $b=\exp(tY)$ for $\exp(t[X,Y])$? (Let $H$ be the group generated by $\exp tX$ and $\exp tY$. Let $h$ be the Lie algebra of $H$. Then $h$ contains $X$ and $Y$. Since $[X,Y]\in h$, $\exp(t[X,Y])\in H$, hence I expect that there is such a formula). By a formula I mean an expression:

$$\exp(t[X,Y])=\exp(t_1X)\exp(s_1Y)\dots\exp(t_kX)\exp(s_kY)$$

where $t_i$, $s_i$ and $k$ are functions of $t,X,Y$.

The Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff series has $1$ product and infinitely many brackets. The Zassenhaus series has infinitely many products and brackets. Is there a similar formula with few brackets and infinitely many products (the above expression would be one with $1$ bracket)?

Comment: Have you looked up Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff?

Comment: I looked up for it on wiki. The Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff series is a formula to compute $e^Xe^Y$ in term of $[X,Y]$. Can you please explain how that helps answer my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not BCH (express group structure in terms of the Lie algebra laws), but rather its inversion (express the Lie algebra laws, here the bracket, in terms of the group law); it's much harder and was addressed/done by Lazard:

Michel Lazard.
*Sur les groupes nilpotents et les anneaux de Lie* (French)
Annales scientifiques de l’É.N.S. 3e série, tome 71, no 2 (1954), p. 101-190. [Freely available at Numdam](http://www.numdam.org/item/ASENS_1954_3_71_2_101_0/)

See notably (2.8) p157.